# How can I run testng.xml file in linux with cmd

Tags: cmd, testng

How can I run testng.xml file in linux with cmd ?

What is command to run in linux command

Comment: yes it is lunix

Comment: How put path? for run xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "path to the testng jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

For testng you need only one jar.So put that in the classpath and for the compiler to understand that it was a testng xml file you have to add "org.testng.TestNG" and run like a normal java program.
The testNG jar file can found in this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng) if you didn't have the jar file
-> You have to remember one thing,The compiled class file must be in the same directory you are running from the test suite xml

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

`cd <Location of TestNGProject> ie. D:\workspace2\TestNG java -cp`

```
D:\workspace2\TestNG\lib\*;D:\workspace2\TestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

`java -cp` argument is used to provide path to classes and libraries that our program need to run

Comment: @kavya how are you running your tests at this moment? can you please write down the command you are currently using?